# Identifying the source of a value in a reactive object on a website

Tags: javascript, python, html

[This website](https://keeptradecut.com/trade-calculator?var=5&pickVal=0&teamOne=365&teamTwo=272%7C1095%7C1361&format=2&isStartup=0) contains a numeric "value adjustment" value (highlighted on the left in the image below) that appears when visitors populate fields elsewhere on the page with certain values.

[image]

My goal is to find the code that calculates the value adjustment. I know that populating the fields that makes this value appear queries a database, but the values from that database are then passed to some sort of program/code somewhere that computes the "value adjustment."

As I'm a novice when it comes to Javascript and web design, my first step was to inspect the elements around the value adjustment in Chrome Developer Mode. As you can see on the right-hand side of the image, it's straightforward to find that value. However, I have no idea how that value was produced.

At a high level, what steps can I take to try to figure this out? For example, does the fact that the value is "hard-coded" in that image as a string imply that there is a script file that is sourced somewhere every time that value is updated? How can I look for/inspect this script? Or are these scripts not observable?

Comment: `document.querySelector(".adjustment-value").text="hello"` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you inspect the elements tab in dev tools you are inspecting what is rendered on the webpage. It always looks hard coded. It's showing you the end result.

If you inspect an element that changes things on the page when it's interacted with, it probably has js 'event listeners' attached to it. [You can inspect the code for the listeners in dev tools](https://www.stanleyulili.com/javascript/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node-when-debugging/) which would reference specific js functions which are called when specific events occur. [You can do essentially the same thing via the console too.](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/get-and-debug-event-listeners/)

Additionally, If you look in the network tab of a web page you can see all the client side files served to you when a page is loaded. You can filter for js files. However, there could also be js embedded within html.

Depending on how the page was made, libraries/frameworks used, and what processing was done to the js before being added to production environment, the js code could be quite a nightmare to attempt to read even if you have an in-depth knowledge of JS.

Comment: Excellent answer in regards to keeping it "high level"